# How to get serial number in digital persona finger print sdk in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I downloaded and run a C++ project for Digital-persona-sdk https://github.com/iamonuwa/Digital-Persona-SDK/ finger print project.That have two projects in after install the sdk. That project only Capture and Verification function only written.Not written for get serial number. Does anyone have an sample program for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minutes of reading the provided documentation tells you everything you need to know:

1. Use `DFPEnumerateDevices` to get all device GUIDs
2. Call `DPFPGetDeviceInfo` to get device info for each device in turn.
3. Serial number is embedded in the device info as `devInfo->HwInfo.szSerialNb`.

Comment: It is a good answer but find i before find the answer. Find the answer in way i post next answer on the this question.

Answer (score 0):

Get serial number answer is:-

```
wchar_t get_serial_number()
{
    DPFPInit();   
    DP_DEVICE_INFO pDevInfo;
    ULONG puDevCount;
    GUID *ppDevUID;
    
    DPFPEnumerateDevices(&puDevCount,&ppDevUID);
    
    GUID sample = *ppDevUID;
    DPFPGetDeviceInfo(sample, &pDevInfo);
    return pDevInfo.HwInfo.szSerialNb;
}
```